# Applying stochastic variational inference to Bayesian Mixture of Gaussian

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, clustering, gaussian-mixture-distribution, variational-bayes

I am trying to implement Gaussian Mixture model with stochastic variational inference, following this [paper](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume14/hoffman13a/hoffman13a.pdf).

[image]

This is the pgm of Gaussian Mixture.

According to the paper, the full algorithm of stochastic variational inference is:
[image]

And I am still very confused of the method to scale it to GMM.

First, I thought the local variational parameter is just $q_z$ and others are all global parameters. Please correct me if I was wrong. What does the step 6 mean by `as though Xi is replicated by N times`? What am I supposed to do to achieve this?

Could you please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's saying that instead of using the whole dataset, sample one datapoint and pretend you have $N$ datapoints of be same size. In many cases, this will be equivalent to multiplying an expectation with one datapoint by $N$.

Comment: @DaeyoungLim Thanks for your reply! I got what you mean now, but I am still confused that which statistics should be updated locally and which ones should be updated globally. For instance, here is a [implementation](https://github.com/jamesmcinerney/vbmm/blob/master/varmix.py#L59) of the mixture of Gaussian, could you tell me how to scale it to svi? I am a little bit lost. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't read the whole code but if you're dealing with a Gaussian mixture model, the mixture component indicator variables should be the local variables since each of them is associated with just one observation. So mixture component latent variables that follow Multinoulli distribution (also known as the Categorical distribution in ML) are $z_{i}, \; i=1,\ldots,N$ in your description above.

Comment: @DaeyoungLim Yes, I understand what you said so far. So for the variational distribution q(Z)q(\pi, \mu, \lambda), q(Z) should be local variable. But there are lots of parameters associated with q(Z). On the other hand, there are also many parameters associated with q(\pi, \mu, \lambda). And I don't know how to update them appropriately.

Comment: You should use the mean-field assumption to get the optimal variational distributions for variational parameters. Here's a reference: http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/jormerod/JTOpapers/Ormerod10.pdf

Answer (score 4):

First, a few notes that help me make sense of the SVI paper:

- In calculating the intermediate value for the variational parameter of the global parameters, we sample one data point and pretend our entire data set of size $N$ was that single point, $N$ times.
- $\eta_g$ is the natural parameter for the full conditional of the global variable $\beta$. The notation is used to stress that it's a function of the conditioned variables, including the observed data.

In a mixture of $k$ Gaussians, our global parameters are the mean and precision (inverse variance) parameters $\mu_k, \tau_k$ params for each. That is, $\eta_g$ is the natural parameter for this distribution, a Normal-Gamma of the form

$$\mu, \tau \sim N(\mu|\gamma, \tau(2\alpha -1)Ga(\tau|\alpha, \beta)$$

with $\eta_0 = 2\alpha - 1$, $\eta_1 = \gamma*(2\alpha -1)$ and $\eta_2 = 2\beta+\gamma^2(2\alpha-1)$. (Bernardo and Smith, *Bayesian Theory*; note this varies a little from the four-parameter Normal-Gamma you'll [commonly see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-gamma_distribution).) We'll use $a, b, m$ to refer to the variational parameters for $\alpha, \beta, \mu$

The full conditional of $\mu_k, \tau_k$ is a Normal-Gamma with params $\dot\eta + \langle\sum_Nz_{n,k}$, $\sum_N z_{n,k}x_N$, $\sum_Nz_{n,k}x^2_{n}\rangle$, where $\dot\eta$ is the prior. (The $z_{n,k}$ in there can also be confusing; it makes sense starting with an $\exp\ln(p))$ trick applied to $\prod_N p(x_n|z_n, \alpha, \beta, \gamma) = \prod_N\prod_K\big(p(x_n|\alpha_k,\beta_k,\gamma_k)\big)^{z_{n,k}}$, and ending with a fair amount of algebra left to the reader.)

With that, we can complete step (5) of the SVI pseudocode with:

$$\phi_{n,k} \propto \exp (ln(\pi) + \mathbb E_q \ln(p(x_n|\alpha_k, \beta_k, \gamma_k))\\
=\exp(\ln(\pi) + \mathbb E_q \big[\langle \mu_k\tau_k, \frac{-\tau}{2} \rangle \cdot\langle x, x^2\rangle - \frac{\mu^2\tau - \ln \tau}{2})\big]
$$

Updating the global parameters is easier, since each parameter corresponds to a count of the data or one of its sufficient statistics:

$$
\hat \lambda = \dot \eta + N\phi_n \langle 1, x, x^2 \rangle
$$

Here's what the marginal likelihood of data looks like over many iterations, when trained on very artificial, easily separable data (code below). The first plot shows the likelihood with initial, random variational parameters and $0$ iterations; each subsequent is after the next power of two iterations. In the code, $a, b, m$ refer to variational parameters for $\alpha, \beta, \mu$.

[image]

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sun Aug 12 12:49:15 2018

@author: SeanEaster
"""

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
from scipy.stats import t
from scipy.special import digamma 

# These are priors for mu, alpha and beta

def calc_rho(t, delay=16,forgetting=1.):
    return np.power(t + delay, -forgetting)

m_prior, alpha_prior, beta_prior = 0., 1., 1.
eta_0 = 2 * alpha_prior - 1
eta_1 = m_prior * (2 * alpha_prior - 1)
eta_2 = 2 *  beta_prior + np.power(m_prior, 2.) * (2 * alpha_prior - 1)

k = 3

eta_shape = (k,3)
eta_prior = np.ones(eta_shape)
eta_prior[:,0] = eta_0
eta_prior[:,1] = eta_1
eta_prior[:,2] = eta_2

np.random.seed(123) 
size = 1000
dummy_data = np.concatenate((
        np.random.normal(-1., scale=.25, size=size),
        np.random.normal(0.,  scale=.25,size=size),
        np.random.normal(1., scale=.25, size=size)
        ))
N = len(dummy_data)
S = 1

# randomly init global params
alpha = np.random.gamma(3., scale=1./3., size=k)
m = np.random.normal(scale=1, size=k)
beta = np.random.gamma(3., scale=1./3., size=k)

eta = np.zeros(eta_shape)
eta[:,0] = 2 * alpha - 1
eta[:,1] = m * eta[:,0]
eta[:,2] = 2. * beta + np.power(m, 2.) * eta[:,0]


phi = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(k) / k, size = dummy_data.shape[0])

nrows, ncols = 4, 5
total_plots = nrows * ncols
total_iters = np.power(2, total_plots - 1)
iter_idx = 0

x = np.linspace(dummy_data.min(), dummy_data.max(), num=200)

while iter_idx < total_iters:

    if np.log2(iter_idx + 1) % 1 == 0:

        alpha = 0.5 * (eta[:,0] + 1)
        beta = 0.5 * (eta[:,2] - np.power(eta[:,1], 2.) / eta[:,0])
        m = eta[:,1] / eta[:,0]
        idx = int(np.log2(iter_idx + 1)) + 1

        f = plt.subplot(nrows, ncols, idx)
        s = np.zeros(x.shape)
        for _ in range(k):
            y = t.pdf(x, alpha[_], m[_], 2 * beta[_] / (2 * alpha[_] - 1))
            s += y
            plt.plot(x, y)
        plt.plot(x, s)
        f.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        f.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    # randomly sample data point, update parameters
    interm_eta = np.zeros(eta_shape)
    for _ in range(S):
        datum = np.random.choice(dummy_data, 1)

        # mean params for ease of calculating expectations
        alpha = 0.5 * ( eta[:,0] + 1)
        beta = 0.5 * (eta[:,2] - np.power(eta[:,1], 2) / eta[:,0])
        m = eta[:,1] / eta[:,0]

        exp_mu = m
        exp_tau = alpha / beta 
        exp_tau_m_sq = 1. / (2 * alpha - 1) + np.power(m, 2.) * alpha / beta
        exp_log_tau = digamma(alpha) - np.log(beta)


        like_term = datum * (exp_mu * exp_tau) - np.power(datum, 2.) * exp_tau / 2 \
            - (0.5 * exp_tau_m_sq - 0.5 * exp_log_tau)
        log_phi = np.log(1. / k) + like_term
        phi = np.exp(log_phi)
        phi = phi / phi.sum()

        interm_eta[:, 0] += phi
        interm_eta[:, 1] += phi * datum
        interm_eta[:, 2] += phi * np.power(datum, 2.)

    interm_eta = interm_eta * N / S
    interm_eta += eta_prior

    rho = calc_rho(iter_idx + 1)

    eta = (1 - rho) * eta + rho * interm_eta

    iter_idx += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial (https://chrisdxie.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/in-depth-variational-inference-tutorial.pdf) answers most of your questions, and would probably be easier to understand than the original SVI paper as it goes specifically through all of the details of implementing SVI (and coordinate ascent VI and gibbs sampling) for a Gaussian mixture model (with known variance).

Answer (score 0):

"Local variational parameter" = variational parameters of the local variables. E.g., in GMM they are the cluster assignment. They are "**local**", because for each data point $x_i$, the corresponding latent variable corresponds only to it. In the paper they denoted this by $z_i$, or $z$ for the entire data vector. We are placing a variational distribution over these $z_i$'s, because of the mean field each one will have its own, and we denote each one by $q(z_i)$. These distributions have parameters. E.g., if they are categorical, they have a vector of probabilities that must sum up to 1. These are the (local) variational parameters denoted by $\phi$.

The "global variational parameters" are the parameters of the global variable. The global variables are denoted in the paper by $\beta$. In GMM they will be the cluster means. They are "**global**" because they don't correspond to a specific data point. They also have a distribution, denoted by $q(\beta)$ and this distribution has parameters denoted in the paper by $\lambda$.

Maybe you are confused to see $z$'s also in the update formula for the global parameters, but this is a property of the model - the global parameters depend on the local ones. E.g., in GMM, the estimation of the cluster means depends on the estimation of which points belong to which cluster. And vice versa, the local parameter update depends on the global parameters - i.e., the estimation of the cluster assignment depends on where I think the means are.

Note that the update rule for the cluster assignments ($z$'s) doesn't suffer when you increase the data size. So, the update rule for it remains a CAVI update rule (for the Expo-Family - which has a simpler update formula of simply updating the natural parameters; in GMM the Expo-Family is a valid assumption as all probabilities belong to it). So, for the i'th point, we will update the cluster assignment (step 5 in the algorithm):

$$\phi_i^{(t+1)} = \mathbb E_{q} [\eta_{\mathcal l} (x_i, \beta)]
$$

The expectation is w.r.t. all other variational distributions ($q$'s) except the $q(\phi_i)$ - in GMM because of the model structure, it means it will only be w.r.t. the $\beta$'s. $\eta$ is the natural parameter of the resulting distribution, $l$ denotes that it's the local one, and it might still be dependent on the values of the data and all the other parameters, and again, in GMM, because of the model structure, it will only depend on the i'th data point $x_i$ and the global parameters $\beta$. It won't depend on other $z$'s.

The CAVI update rule for the global parameters $\beta$ might be hard to scale, as it requires going over the entire data. To "combat" this SVI uses (stochastic) gradient ascent instead of coordinate ascent (CAVI) for the global parameters. It does so by also taking the natural gradient in Riemannian space instead of the regular gradient in Euclidian space. After a lot of math, this turns out to be almost identical to CAVI. In CAVI the update rules are (almost) the term specified in step 6 in the algorithm:

$$ \lambda^{(t+1)} = \mathbb E_{q} [\eta_{\mathcal g} (x, z)]
$$

In regular CAVI you would have to take the expectation w.r.t. the entire data set ($x$'s) and local variables ($z$'s). In SVI you replace it with N replications of the same (randomly sampled) $x_i,z_i$. E.g., for GMM, and for $\beta_1$ supposing 1D data, the true (natural parameter) CAVI update rules will be (corresponding to $\mu/\sigma^2$, $-1/2\sigma^2$ natural parameters):

$$\lambda_{11}^{(t+1)} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb E[z_{i1}]x_i \\
\lambda_{12}^{(t+1)} = -0.5(\frac{1}{\sigma^2} + \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E[z_{i1}]) 
$$

These will turn to:

$$\lambda_{11}^{(t+1)} = n \cdot \mathbb E[z_{i1}]x_i \\
\lambda_{12}^{(t+1)} = -0.5(\frac{1}{\sigma^2} + n \cdot \mathbb E[z_{i1}]) 
$$

As mentioned, this is the CAVI update, but we want gradient ascent, and so step 7 does the (stochastic) gradient ascent.

If you want to learn more, I suggest you check out my [YouTube video on the topic](https://youtu.be/Wyl8kutRLLA), and my [medium article](https://medium.com/@david_39639/stochastic-variational-inference-6e7dae48ab8b).